# angular - update directive template on click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a page using Angular.

I have two templates, say

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='a.html'>
    /*some html using {{data}} */
    <div><button>A</button></div>
</script>
```

and

```
<script type='text/ng-template' id='b.html'>
    /*some html using {{data}} */
    <div><button>B</button></div>
</script>
```

I would like to create a directive that changes its template from a to b and vice versa when the button inside the template gets clicked.
I tried several options, looking at other answers to similar questions, but without any luck.
Can you help me to find the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ng-include` is a nifty directive that accepts a scope variable as the parameter. this way, you can dynamically load (including other directives from the loaded templates). See the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/qxBVDWx6P0F0aNuOymct?p=preview

```js
app.directive('dynamicTemplate', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><div ng-include="var"></div><div>current var: {{ var }}</div></div>',
    controller: function($scope){
      $scope.var = 'template1.html';
      $scope.change = function(where){
        $scope.var = where;
      }
    }
  };
});
```

but the best way would be just deal with either using `$stateProvider` or `$routeProvider`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer that doesn't use `ng-include`

http://jsfiddle.net/5DGkT/

It basically grabs it from the template cache and compiles it

```
if (newVal) {
    element.html($templateCache.get(newVal.type + '.html'));
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}
```

Comment: I upvoted also your answer, but I choose the other since it seems more angular-oriented. Yours looks to me something similar to what I would have done with jquery