# Can an AngularJS controller link a scope variable in it to an HTML file, the variable then being referenced to render the HTML file?

Tags: html, angularjs, templates, controller, render

I see examples that show directives rendering an HTML file in lieu of the directive. Or controllers rendering an HTML snippet as a scope variable, written directly between single quotation marks - like

```
$scope.items = '<ol><li>an item></li> <li>another item</li></ol>'
```

(this does not work well for me because I have other single quotation marks in the middle of my HTML snippet that seem to stop the HTML snippet from rendering properly.)

**Here is something I tried that did not work:**

Controller code:

```
innerapp.controller('ResourcesController', function($scope, $sce, $http) {

$scope.template = 'employeelists.html';
});
```

HTML code:

```
 <div ng-controller="ResourcesController">

      <div ng-bind-html-unsafe="template"></div>
    </div>
```

I have 'employeelists.html' in my app/assets/templates folder. I am using AngularJS with Rails, and this setup already lets me call the file like this:

```
div ng-include="'employeelists.html'"></div>
```

But I want the controller, instead of ng-include, to render the HTML file.

Basically, I am working on functionality such that if I select an item on the HTML page (under this AngularJS controller), a function in the controller gets called that updates the scope variable (that's linked to a template file) with another template file.

Comment: Doesn't combining both answers, gives what you want? `$scope.template = 'employeelists.html';` and `<div ng-include="template"></div>`

Comment: I did not realize that is how you go about it. So by updating the template variable through the controller, what "ng-include" renders also changes? That's cool, I will check it out.

Comment: klauskpm, do you recommend the approach with a directive or with a controller to render a changing template variable here, according to selections made in the HTML?

Comment: klauskpm, your method worked for me (a scope variable that refers to an HTML file in 'app/assets/templates', and ng-include calling that scope variable).

Answer (score 1):

First, please keep in mind DOM manipulation should allways be left to directives, not controllers. Second, I would highly recommend you looked into views using ui-router. This could easily accomplish what you want to do. Here is an example of simple view changing: 
https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Also, someone already found a way to input code to the ng-include directive so you could update it:
[angular - update directive template on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22570717/angular-update-directive-template-on-click)

However, do read the answer above how he also recommends you use $stateProvider (ui-routers state configurator) since it would be a much easier approach to what you are trying to do.

I hope this helps

Comment: <div ui-view></div> is not working for me at all. I did try ui-router first.  I have configured ui-router with Rails with things like "angular-rails-templates" according to an online guide I found that seemed reliable: http://start.jcolemorrison.com/angularjs-rails-4-1-and-ui-router-tutorial/

Comment: I will check out the resource you provided. ui-router is doing SOMETHING with Rails (like it is trying to add the 'url' part to the end of the browser URL), but just not rendering the HTML template file included in templateURL (the template file being in the app/assets/templates folder).

Comment: if you are starting off, I recommend that before trying to wire up everything, try to first configure ui-router, and then try to access each file individually from the url. For example: with the following configuration: ...

angular.module('ngModule').config(function($stateProvider) { $stateProvider.$state('myState', { url: '/my-state-url' , templateUrl: '[insert your file directory here]' } );  })

 ... I would try accessing localhost:8080/#/my-state-url to see if it loads. I'd try to help, but I develop mainly in nodeJS and express. Good luck!

Comment: Also, try this if you are stuck, it was a lot of help to me when I was just starting up, it's a quick get-started guide for ui-router:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-routing-using-ui-router